# Using lt method in the superclass even if it is overrided in the subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,grade,age,degree):
        self.__name=name
        self.__grade=grade
        self.__age=age
        self.__degree=degree
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return (self.__name,self.__grade)<(other.__name,other.__grade)
    
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,grade,age,degree):
        Person.__init__(self,name,grade,age,degree)
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return (self._Person__age,self._Person__degree)<(other._Person__age,other._Person__degree)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {} {} {}'.format(self._Person__name,self._Person__grade,self._Person__age,self._Person__degree)
studentdata=[]

L=['Xavi;90;21;4','Richard;100;20;3','Alex;80;20;5','Alex;95;19;1']

for student in L:
    elements=student.split(';')
    name=elements[0]
    grade=int(elements[1])
    age=int(elements[2])
    degree=int(elements[3])
    student=Student(name,grade,age,degree)
    studentdata.append(student)

studentdata.sort()
print('Name Grade Age Degree')
for i in studentdata:
    print(i)
```

---

```
Output:
Name Grade Age Degree
Alex 95 19 1
Richard 100 20 3
Alex 80 20 5
Xavi 90 21 4
```

---

```
Expected Output:
Name Grade Age Degree
Alex 80 20 5
Alex 95 19 1
Richard 100 20 3
Xavi 90 21 4
```

Hello, I want to sort student data according to their names and grades even if I override the `lt` method in the subclass. It currently makes a comparison according to their age and degree. The current and expected output is above. How can I do that without deleting the `lt` method in the subclass? Please don't use special functions from the py library if possible. I think there could be a usage of the desired `lt` method with sort outside the classes.

Comment: It's not possible without (at least temporarily) getting rid of the method on the subclass. You could do `studentdata.sort(key=lambda x: (x._Person__name, x._Person__grade))` though.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Why are you double-underscore-prefixing the attributes on the parent class if you're anyways going to circumvent the "hiding" of attributes by going via `._Person__*`?

Comment: **Stop using double-underscore name mangling if you don't need double-underscore name-mangling**

Comment: In any case, if you want to sort a list of objects based on *some other* property that isn't how their comparisons work then use a key function to `sort`. Note, your `Student` object breaks the Liskov substitution principle.